# Python Server on OSX only pulling from old site package

Tags: python, django, macos

I am trying to set up a virtual environment for Django on OSX, and have completed the installation of pyenv and Python 3.5.  When it's time to load the project using $python manage.py runserver, it gives me the following error location:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/
```

Even though I tried using the following two commands:

```
$set global python for everytime we start pyenv pyenv global 3.4.3 
$set python version for current and all sub directories pyenv local 3.4.3
```

What am I missing? Any help much appreciated

Comment: Did you activate your virtualenv?

Comment: yes, I did source bin/activate and my CLI reflects it

Comment: so when you `which python` what is it?

Comment: If I do python, it says 3.4.3, but if I do which python, it says
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

When creating a virtual environment, you can specify the interpreter to use.

mkvirtualenv -p /path/to/python nameOfEnv

This might not be what you're looking for but I don't have the reputation to just leave this as a comment.